# Android: How to pass Serializable object from one activity to another?

Tags: java, android, object, serialization

OK so I am passing a Serializable object from one activity to another like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(GetVariants.this, RoadDetails.class);
i.putExtra("Variant", (Serializable)trips[0]);
```

and I receive the object on the other activity like this:

```
trip1 = (HashMap<String, Object>) intent.getSerializableExtra("Variant");
variant1 = new Variant();
variant1.Read(trip1);
```

So far so good things are working great but how can I send variant1 to another activity and how to receive it?

Comment: `So far so good things are working great but how can I send variant1 to another activity and how to receive it?`. You did it in the first place. What's stopping you doing it again?

Comment: you mean its the same? I do i.putExtra("Variant", (Serializable)variant1); and receive it with the same code?

Comment: yes of course. As long as Variant is `Serializable` (it meant that class implements the `Serializable` interface)

Comment: yes the class "Variant" is Serializable but do I put intent.putExtra("Variant", (Serializable)  trip1 or variant1?